# good free software (or code) to separate multiples sources in a single wav?

Tags: matlab, source-separation

For a school project I'm working on instrument classification on multi-instrumental tracks. To do so, I'm following Arie Livshin's modus operandi, and I would like to get a good software to perform source separation: given a multi-instrumental short extract, getting n (with n being equal to the number of instruments) tracks with more or less one instrument per track.

The best I've found so far is the FASST toolbox for Matlab, but the result on a saxophone/guitar song was quite disappointing. Have anyone encountered something better I could use?

Comment: This is an active research topic. As mentioned in the answer below, this is a blind source separation problem. JADE is a specific example of one of these algorithms, but you are unlikely to be very successful with one audio source.

Comment: I did a search recently but could not find anything better than FASST in free alternatives.

Comment: Your question has beeen answered. Do not hesitate to vote for the useful ones and accept the most suitable

Comment: I am working on a blind source seperation project. My main task is to seperate voices of different people and store them separately from a single .wav file. Can anyone help me ,

Comment: @SaurabhNikamSN : Welcome to SE.SP!  You added your question as an answer, which is not the way we organize this site. If you have a question that is not answered on this question, [please ask a new question!](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 1):

A great free toolbox is the [Flexible Audio Source Separation](http://bass-db.gforge.inria.fr/fasst/). Their website contains some demo examples in Python, Matlab, and C++ code.

Another toolbox is the [Toolbox for Blind Source Separation](http://www-public.tem-tsp.eu/~castella/toolbox/). However, this toolbox is not user friendly and you need to do some extra programming in C, Matlab or Python.

Answer (score 0):

You could try analysing your audio sample with [Independent Component Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_component_analysis). It is a blind source separation technique which assumes that the multivariate signal sample is a linear mixture of mutually independent (non-Gaussian) source signals. The de-facto implementation for Matlab is a fast fixed-point iteration algorithm called [FastICA](http://research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/fastica/).

Comment: Not sure if I read the question correctly, but does this *.wav file have multiple independent sources(not instruments)?

Answer (score 0):

A recent paper is [Monaural Music Source Separation using Convolutional Sparse Coding](http://math.lanl.gov/~brendt/Publications/Docs/jao-2016-monaural.pdf), IEEE/ACM Transactions on Audio, Speech, and Language Processing (TASLP), accepted for publication (2016). The algorithm [Convolutional Sparse Coding based Source Separation](http://mac.citi.sinica.edu.tw/research/CSC_separation/) uses the [SPORCO library](http://math.lanl.gov/~brendt/Software/SPORCO/). No guitar, but saxophone, with the use of a dictionary.

> We present a comprehensive performance study of a new time-domain
>   approach for estimating the components of an observed monaural audio
>   mixture. Unlike existing time-frequency approaches that use the
>   product of a set of spectral templates and their corresponding
>   activation patterns to approximate the spectrogram of the mixture, the
>   proposed approach uses the sum of a set of convolutions of estimated
>   activations with prelearned dictionary filters to approximate the
>   audio mixture directly in the time domain. The approximation problem
>   can be solved by an efficient convolutional sparse coding algorithm.
>   The effectiveness of this approach for source separation of musical
>   audio has been demonstrated in our prior work, but under rather
>   restricted and controlled conditions, requiring the musical score of
>   the mixture being informed a priori and little mismatch between the
>   dictionary filters and the source signals. In this paper, we report an
>   evaluation that considers wider, and more practical, experimental
>   settings. This includes the use of an audio-based multi-pitch
>   estimation algorithm to replace the musical score, and an external
>   dataset of audio single notes to construct the dictionary filters. Our
>   result shows that the proposed approach remains effective with a
>   larger dictionary, and compares favorably with the state-of-the-art
>   non-negative matrix factorization approach. However, in the absence of
>   the score and in the case of a small dictionary, our approach may not
>   be better